# Old Script in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

How can I use next CODE in HTML5?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" for="KM701" event="EventSignButton(nCh)">
```

This code have warning in Eclipse.

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Attribute (for) is obsolete. Its use is discouraged in HTML5 documents.
    - Attribute (event) is obsolete. Its use is discouraged in HTML5 
     documents.
    - Attribute (language) is obsolete. Its use is discouraged in HTML5 
     documents.
```

Comment: Please paste your code first so that people can help you

Comment: Just remove the obsolete attributes.

Comment: @PatrissolKenfack He did, he just didn't format it correctly.

Comment: Use external JavaScript. Tag should look like `<script src='yourJavaScriptPage.js'></script>`.

Comment: @StackSlave That's a style opinion, and it has nothing to do with the warnings.

Comment: Actually, even having `type='text/javascript'` will no longer validate at [w3.org](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea).

Comment: @StackSlave Thank!  But I can't use independent script. because This Project use limitative UI/UX Tool.

Comment: You can always use external JavaScript, if you know what you're doing.